# Which repositories are pip packages installed from?

Tags: python, pip

I need to download a package using pip. I ran `pip install <package>` but got the following error:

```
[user@server ~]$ pip install sistr_cmd
Collecting sistr_cmd
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.
VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f518ee0cd90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/sistr-cmd/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.
VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f518ee0c290>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/sistr-cmd/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.
VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f518ee0c510>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/sistr-cmd/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.
VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f518ee0cf10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/sistr-cmd/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.
VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f518ee0c190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/sistr-cmd/

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sistr_cmd (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sistr_cmd
```

I verified that the source of the problem is the network blocking most sites because I am working behind a proxy (required by the organization). To allow these downloads, I need to compile the list of urls of the source of the downloads and send it to the network admins to unblock.

According to pip documentation (cited and explained in brief in the pip Wikipedia article), “Many packages can be found in the default source for packages and their dependencies — Python Package Index (PyPI)," so I went to the PyPI page for Biopython and found the github repository and the required dependencies for the package. There are also download links on the PyPI page and I want to be sure that all sources for the download are allowed. So does pip install from the original source of a package (the github repository or wherever the original package is hosted), the packages listed in the PyPI page under downloads, or does it search through both?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Please post text like error output as text, not screenshots. That screenshot is hard enough to read on a laptop, and even harder on a phone. Also, if there's any useful information in it that could be copied and pasted for others to look up in a search engine or try to experiment with, they can't do so with a screenshot.

Comment: Anyway, if you run `pip` with the `--verbose` flag, it will show you all the links it considers. Generally speaking, it goes to `https://pypi.org/simple/{PACKAGE}` first. That page will have links to downloads for wheels and source for all versions that the maintainer has uploaded, and it will look for the appropriate version's wheel by trying its links in order. Usually there is no github repo listed as a source.

Comment: If you want to install everything from `github` (or any other location) that you know, the simplest thing to do is to manually give the repo to `pip` instead of just the package names. Ideally, install everything you care about that way on a machine that isn't firewalled from most of the internet, build a `requirements.txt` file (as explained [here](http://codeinthehole.com/tips/using-pip-and-requirementstxt-to-install-from-the-head-of-a-github-branch/), then copy that requirements file to your firewalled machine and try to install it.

Comment: If you can't find _any_ (http, https, git, etc.‚ URLs that are reachable from your firewalled machine, you will either need to copy the files manually to the machine, or copy them to a repo inside the firewall. At which point you might want to consider building a local pip repo to put everything in (which is explained in the docs you were reading, but isn't exactly trivial, so you may find yourself getting stuck and coming back to SO with a new question…).

Comment: One last thing: Have you considered asking your organization to either unblock the sites you need, or set up an official way of accessing the files you need from them (e.g., by setting up their own pip repo or special proxy)? If they want you to install these packages for your work, they should be willing to do that, and if they don't want you to install these packages, better to find out now than when you're ready to deploy and can't get clearance for the code you've been working on for 5 months because it uses an unvetted library.

Comment: The `--verbose` flag does the trick. I am thinking of installing into another machine that does not have a strict firewall and then moving it to the server as a temporary workaround. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I spoke to the network administrators and they require the specific urls that I need unblocked because they also have to document it.

Comment: In that case, I'd consider installing everything to a clean Python on the non-firewalled machine, then using `pip freeze` to generate a requirements file with not just specific versions but specific URLs. This guarantees that you won't get hosed by newer versions, and it will also generate the list of URLs to pass to your admins, and it's not that much harder than downloading and copying over the wheels/tarballs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to user [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert):

"If you run `pip` with the `--verbose` flag, it will show you all the links it considers. Generally speaking, it goes to `https://pypi.org/simple/{PACKAGE}` first. That page will have links to downloads for wheels and source for all versions that the maintainer has uploaded, and it will look for the appropriate version's wheel by trying its links in order. Usually there is no github repo listed as a source.
If you want to install everything from github (or any other location) that you know, the simplest thing to do is to manually give the repo to pip instead of just the package names. Ideally, install everything you care about that way on a machine that isn't firewalled from most of the internet, build a requirements.txt file (as explained [here](http://codeinthehole.com/tips/using-pip-and-requirementstxt-to-install-from-the-head-of-a-github-branch/)), then copy that requirements file to your firewalled machine and try to install it."

Running `pip install` with the `--verbose` flag shows extensive detail about where the package is being pulled from and about the network connection and traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It appears a network connection, later you may try below:

`pip install sistr-cmd` 
See the difference between `-` and `_` for more info check [here](https://pypi.org/project/sistr-cmd/)

Comment: I get the same error. This is a network issue not pip. Thanks for the suggestion though